# Command option in Visual Studio Properties Window right click menu not working

Tags: c#, properties, propertygrid, form-designer

When right clicking on the Properties Window, a menu is shown as in the image.  Turning on or off the 'Description' option will show or hide the bottom part, in this case showing "The cursor that appears...".

However, changing the 'Commands' option has no visible effect.  How does it work?

[image: Right click menu on Properties Window]

Comment: It's used to toggle displaying *designer verbs* (from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx)). I don't know what are those and how they are used.

Comment: [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57760/Exposing-Object-Methods-in-the-PropertyGrid-Comman) is some tutorial explaining verbs.

Comment: I thought it could provide some concise interface or class info of the property to help coding, just like the function of "Description" under the same menu.

Comment: I've skimmed through the tutorial you linked, although details in the article is beyond my ability, it seems to be a way of running code, to use certain method related to the selected property.